# grep won't stop sending data to a string

Tags: bash, grep

I have a very simple script that scans a file for a string and if it finds it, it sends that string to a file. My problem is that the command loops forever and I can't see a logical reason why.

```
key=0
while [ $key = 0 ]
  do
     if [ $key = 0 ]
      then
      tail -1 /home/user/testfile | grep -i string >> holder
      key=1
        else
        key=0
     fi
 done
```

I want the script to scan the `testfile` for a string until it finds it, but right now it's not stopping when it finds the string, it just keeps sending the string to the holder file.

Comment: Would it be possible for the OP to indent the question for readability? There are two syntax error (that I can spot right away), there is no space between 0 and the ] in the while statement and no space between if and [ so something is off with the question, right?

Comment: fix, sorry about that

Comment: Have you already "echoed" the value of 'key' to know what is going on?

Comment: Hi, the piece of code you posted should not do more than one iteration ever, and actually is equivalent to simply writing `tail -1 /home/user/testfile | grep -i string >> holder`. Is it exactly the code you run that makes the problem or is there also something else?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, *total* rewrite.

```
while read line
do case "$line" in
   *string*) echo "$line"
             break ;;
   esac
done < <( tail -99999f testfile ) >> holder
```

The `tail` controls feed rate. It needs a number of lines if the file has any data you want to check when the loop begins; the number I used is arbitrary. The `-f` will follow along the end of the file passing new data as it arrives.

`read` isn't the most efficient possible system, but here it helps with buffering issues, so I think it's appropriate.

The `case` is a simple string compare that replaces the `grep` without spawning a process every line. This ought to be pretty efficient, and doesn't need governors like `sleep` - it will keep up with `tail` as best it can and then be done in one pass.

...it's leaving the `tail` running, though. I expected it to close when there was no one reading the pipe. Hmm...

Comment: Paul Hodges, thank you for the suggestion, ive tried  to make the grep the condition for the while and the if but now it just prints the string endlessly to my terminal and prints it endlessly into my file

Comment: ok so i switched the while for the until and it works just like i want now thanks